# Implementar uma API para regras de negócio de um site web: é um exagero? Ou é uma boa prática?

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core

Em alguns lugares que trabalhei com C# MVC vi duas formas de se programar o modelo de negócio de um sistema web, sendo elas: codificando dentro do Controller da aplicação web; criando uma web API rest e criando a regra de negócio na API, apenas chamando essa API dentro do Controller da aplicação web.

Só para ficar claro, um exemplo:

Uma aplicação que faz um cadastro de um cliente, no MVC existirá uma View chamada 'Cadastrar.cshtml' com código html e razor criando um formulário de cadastro. Ao clicar em cadastrar, os dados do formulário serão enviados ao Controller Cadastrar.cs, e é aí que entram as diferenças.

Eu posso simplesmente já cadastrar o cliente ali mesmo no Controller ou eu posso criar uma Web API rest que faça essa ação, então no Controller eu só chamaria essa API. Desta maneira, meu aplicativo web teria basicamente as views, mas sem acesso a banco de dados ou regras de negócio, e essas regras ficariam todas na API.

A questão é: é melhor fazer assim? Porquê?
Penso que possa ser um exagero e que até prejudique a performance, mas já ouvi dizer que é uma boa prática, justamente porque a regra de negócio fica na API.

Comment: Primeiro, a regra de negócio não deve estar na `Controller`. Segundo, a questão da WebAPI seria muito útil se você quer disponibilizar as funcionalidades para outros clientes que não estejam dentro da sua solution  ou que não sejam .net. Aí vem a vantagem da regra de negócio não estar implemantada na `Controller` e sim em uma camada isolada, pois assim você pode expor e acessá-la conforme for a sua necessidade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto seria ter uma segunda camada de "Serviços" que terá suas regras de negócios (nunca direto na controller).

O uso da API faz sentido para projetos médios/grandes (facilita a manutenção), e para reutilização de código (para outros sistemas).